# how to change dynamical attribute on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I have a dynamical slider. And trying to add `tabindex="-1"` attribute to child when it's parent `li` element has `aria-hidden="true"` attribute.

Here is [Fiddle example :](https://jsfiddle.net/5fjsybq8/61/)

Or see below snippet :

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideWidth: 150,
  slideMargin: 0
});

$('li[aria-hidden=true]').children().attr('tabindex', '-1');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 0 0 30px;
}

.my-slider {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="my-slider bxslider">
  <li><a href="#">aaa</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">bbb</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">ccc</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">dd</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">eee</a> </li>
</ul>
```

How do I change the code as dynamical attribute ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Louys reported you should use onSlideAfter calback function :

but some small addition in order to remove tabindex you should remove from all li's children that add it to li with `aria-hidden=true`

by adding `$('.bxslider li').children().removeAttr('tabindex');`

See below Snippet :

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideWidth: 150,
  slideMargin: 0,
  onSlideAfter : function(elt,oldIndex,neIndex) {
   $('.bxslider li').children().removeAttr('tabindex');
   $('li[aria-hidden=true]').children().attr('tabindex', '-1');
  }
});

$('li[aria-hidden=true]').children().attr('tabindex', '-1');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 0 0 30px;
}

.my-slider {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="my-slider bxslider">
  <li><a href="#">aaa</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">bbb</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">ccc</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">dd</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">eee</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the BxSlider `onSlideAfter` callback.

> Executes immediately after each slide transition. Function argument is the current slide element (when transition completes).

See [documentation](https://bxslider.com/options/).

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideWidth: 150,
  slideMargin: 0,

  onSlideAfter: function(){
    $('li[aria-hidden=true]').children().attr('tabindex', '-1');
  }
});
```

Your [Fiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/c8vqrfgn/).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this though... And you probably also have to remove that attribute for the visible elements...